# SQL Server has float number less than 2.23E-308 (minimum of double precision number)

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, precision

We are using SQL Server 2014 to store results from a C library. Recent we found that there are some values like 1.39202924295074E-309 stored in a column defined as a float.

This is weird because based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the float range is

```
 -1.79E+308 to -2.23E-308, 0 and 2.23E-308 to 1.79E+308
```

by default which is consistent with any literature I found.

So the question is why we got value smaller than the minimum allowed?

The table is designed something like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CLibDataResult](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Result] [float] NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: how is the data being added? and how are you querying the value out of the database?

Comment: the data is the result of a legacy C lib. I can just select * from thattable

Comment: I think it is the result of 'extra' decimal places kept to try and prevent round-off

Comment: Double precision has 15 digits at least

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging on the internet, I think I can answer my question. One of the references is this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_math.html) and this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

There are two concepts here, one is the minimum positive normal number and the minimum positive `subnormal` number. The MSDN page lists the ranges based on the minimum positive `normal` number. But based on IEEE 754, the minimum positive subnormal number is the smallest positive number representable in the double-extended format.

Here is a cheat sheet for these numbers for double precision,

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| max normal number             |   1.7976931348623157e+308  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| min positive normal number    | 2.2250738585072014e-308    |
--------------------------------------------------------------                                           
| max subnormal number          |   2.2250738585072009e-308  |
--------------------------------------------------------------                                           
| min positive subnormal number |   4.9406564584124654e-324  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

In conclusion, the minimum representable is 4.9406564584124654e-324 and 1.39E-309 is larger than that. So SQL server conforms to IEEE standard for double precision.

Answer (score 0):

Strange as it may seem, the value you give is within the range.  If you use .NET, you can test it with this code:

```
var d = double.Parse("1.39202924295074E-309");
var min = double.Parse("-1.79E+308");            
Console.WriteLine(d > min);  // returns true
```

I think the MSDN text is confusing.

Comment: why is it within the range?

Comment: To be honest, I'm no math whiz, but I believe -1.79E+308 is a really small negative number.  1.39202924295074E-309 is a positive number (still really small, but more than zero, and thus way bigger than -1.79E+308).

Comment: what if you used double.Parse("1.3E-500"); ?

Comment: You can't parse that value into a double; it's too big (well, small...)

Comment: -1.79E+308  is a massive negative number (309 digits long).  Think of E+308 moving the decimal point 308 places to the right (with zeroes appearing where needed).  1.39202924295074E-309 is indeed a tiny positive number (so larger than zero and larger than any negative number - you are right on that)

Answer (score 0):

if you start off with this

```
update [CLibDataResult] set result = power(cast(10.000 as float),-300);
```

or

```
 INSERT [CLibDataResult] VALUES(power(cast(10.000 as float),-300));
```

and then repeatedly run

```
update [CLibDataResult] set result = result / 10;
select * from [CLibDataResult];
```

you can watch the value get smaller, then around e-308 its precision seems to fall to pieces as there are less digits somehow available, finally it just vanishes to zero